# C++ noob - class scoping

Tags: c++, redis

I have the following C++ class:

```
class Eamorr {
public:
        redispp::Connection conn;

        Eamorr(string& home, string& uuid)
        {
            //redispp::Connection conn("127.0.0.1", "6379", "password", false);   //this works, but is out of scope in put()...
            conn=new redispp::Connection("127.0.0.1", "6379", "password", false);   //this doesn't work ;(
        }
        put(){
            conn.set("hello", "world");
        }
        ...
}
```

As you can see, I want `conn` to be initialised in the constructor and available in the `put()` method.

How can I do this?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what member-initialization-list is for:

```
 Eamorr(string& home, string& uuid) 
     : conn("127.0.0.1", "6379", "password", false) 
 {
    //constructor body!
 }
```

The syntax  after `:` ( and including this) forms member-initiazation-list. You can initialize the members here,  each member separated by comma.

Here is an elaborated example:

```
struct A
{
     int n;
     std::string s;
     B *pB;

     A() : n(100), s("some string"), pB(new B(n, s))
     {
        //ctor-body!
     }
};
```

For more, see these:

- [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)
- [Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) (FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Nawaz answer.

The thing that was actually wrong was that you used new for a variable that wasn't a pointer. So as the variable conn isn't a pointer you could have written:

```
Eamorr(string& home, string& uuid)
{
    conn = redispp::Connection("127.0.0.1", "6379", "password", false);
}
```